# Why doesn't "strip(,.)" also strip ","s?

Tags: python

I'm doing this python tutorial on kaggle.com. This is my current task:

"A researcher has gathered thousands of news articles. But she wants to focus her attention on articles including a specific word. Complete the function below to help her filter her list of articles.

Your function should meet the following criteria

- Do not include documents where the keyword string shows up only as a part of a larger word. For example, if she were looking for the keyword “closed”, you would not include the string “enclosed.”
- She does not want you to distinguish upper case from lower case letters. So the phrase “Closed the case.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”
- Do not let periods or commas affect what is matched. “It is closed.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”. But you can assume there are no other types of punctuation."

This is what I tried:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    mylist = []

    for ele in doc_list:
        if len([ele for ele in ele.lower().strip(".,").split() if ele == keyword.lower()]) > 0:
            mylist.append(doc_list.index(ele))

    return mylist
```

But this example

```
doc_list=['The Learn Python Challenge Casino.', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?']
word_search(doc_list, 'car')
```

gives me `[]` instead of the expected `[1]` (as 'car' is included in the second string).

For debugging, I altered my code to

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
for ele in doc_list:
    print([ele for ele in ele.lower().rstrip('.,').split()])
```

and I get

```
['the', 'learn', 'python', 'challenge', 'casino']
['they', 'bought', 'a', 'car,', 'and', 'a', 'horse']
['casinoville?']
```

As you can see, the "," with "car," remains although I tried to strip(".,") it. Any ideas about why this is the case?
If I try `"car,".strip(".,")` I get the expected `'car'`.

Thanks!

---

Edit: Thanks for the help - I didn't know that it strips only on the edges. Here are two solutions for future readers:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    mylist = []

    for ele in doc_list:
        tmp = [ele.lower().strip(".,") for ele in ele.split()]
        if len([ele for ele in tmp if ele == keyword]) > 0:
            mylist.append(doc_list.index(ele))

#         if len([ele.strip(".,") for ele in ele.lower().split() if ele.strip(".,") == keyword.lower()]) > 0:
#             mylist.append(doc_list.index(ele))
    return mylist
```

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but note that `'They bought a car, and a horse'.strip(".,")` gives `'They bought a car, and a horse'`. In other words, `strip()` only strips characters off of either end of the string.

Comment: Stripping doesn't remove characters from the middle, only from the *ends*.

Comment: Split first, *then* strip.

Comment: What you want is `ele.rstrip(",.") for ele in...` so it gets stripped from each word.

Comment: @kindall: That won't work because unstripped `ele` would be used in the comprehension's restriction clause.

Comment: `for idx,element in enumerate(doc_list):` `if keyword_lower in {ele.strip(".,") for ele in element.lower().split()}:` `mylist.append(idx)` might be better overall - list.index("something") can be costly.

Answer (score 1):

You are stripping the whole sentence, not each word individually. `car,` is in the middle of the sentence, so it won't get stripped. Change to:

```
    if len([ele for ele in ele.lower().split()
            if ele.strip(".,") == keyword.lower()]
          ) > 0:
```